# reformatting data received from api callback string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I am receiving from a php/curl callback to an api and using jquery if statements to output certain data.

For one particular call back string the data is returned like so:

```
response.endpoints[0].details.cert.subject
```

The value of the above string is:

> CN=www.thawte.com,OU=Infrastructure Operations,2.5.4.5=#130733383938323631,2.5.4.15=#131450726976617465204f7267616e697a6174696f6e,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US,O=Thawte, Inc.,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=#0c0844656c6177617265,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=#13025553

What I would like to be able to achieve is extract certain parts of this string instead of displaying the entire value.

The following are fixed values which will always appear but I dont want the rest of the stuff..

How can I seperately extract the following bits:

- CN=value
- OU=value
- L=value
- ST=value
- C=value

For example, in my output I want to set a variable to end up with "www.thawte.com" and a seperate variable for the each of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use foreach inside another foreach like this:

```
$(function(){
    var valData= "CN=www.thawte.com,OU=Infrastructure Operations,2.5.4.5=#130733383938323631,2.5.4.15=#131450726976617465204f7267616e697a6174696f6e,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US,O=Thawte, Inc.,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=#0c0844656c6177617265,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=#13025553";

    var valNew=valData.split(/,(?=\S)/);
    var valArray_unprep = [];
    var valArray_prep = [];

    for(var i=0;i<valNew.length;i++){

    var valArray_unprep = valNew[i].split('=');

        for(var ii=0;ii<valArray_unprep.length;ii++)
            valArray_prep[valArray_unprep[0]] = valArray_unprep[1];

    }
 console.log(valArray_prep);    

    alert(valArray_prep['CN']);
    alert(valArray_prep['L']);
});
```

Comment: seems to work if i explicitly set the value like you did but I need to reference the typeof string.. i tried this but i get an error in the web console "TypeError: valData.split is not a function".. Is something wrong with using this: **var valData= parseInt(response.endpoints[0].details.cert.subject);**

Comment: i should also mention if i do window.alert(response.endpoints[0].details.cert.subject); I do get the full value so I know its the right string..

Comment: never mind it worked without the parseInt() ..like this: var valData= response.endpoints[0].details.cert.subject;

Comment: Motto, there is one issue found with your code.. for example O=Thawte, Inc is being cut short and ,Inc is seperated. the end result is "Thawte" however the ",Inc" is part of the value.. not sure if we can do anything about it?

Comment: @user3436467 ok, i've added a regex which is checks white space before splitting. try again.